# How to prepend timestamp to the STDERR and redirect to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm redirecting only the STDERR to a file (which is more or less working) but I also want to add/prepend a time-stamp for each redirection. I don't want the time in every line, just at the beginning of the block. I tried this:

```
UKMAC08:~ san$ ( date 1>&2; df -jj ) 2>&1 1>/dev/null  2>testErr.log; cat testErr.log 
Fri  1 Aug 2014 10:50:00 BST
df: illegal option -- j
usage: df [-b | -H | -h | -k | -m | -g | -P] [-ailn] [-T type] [-t] [filesystem ...]
```

Which is doing what I want to do for an unsuccessful run but also putting the time-stamp when it's  a success:

```
UKMAC08:~ san$ ( date 1>&2; df -h ) 2>&1 1>/dev/null  2>testErr.log; cat testErr.log 
Fri  1 Aug 2014 10:50:07 BST
```

How can I avoid that. Best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can do:

```
OUT=$(df -h 2>&1 >/dev/null) || { date; echo "$OUT"; } >testErr.log
```

Test:

```
$ : > testErr.log; OUT=$(df -jj 2>&1 >/dev/null) || { date -u; echo "$OUT"; } >testErr.log; cat testErr.log
Fri Aug  1 12:10:29 UTC 2014
df: invalid option -- 'j'
Try 'df --help' for more information.
$ : > testErr.log; OUT=$(df -h 2>&1 >/dev/null) || { date -u; echo "$OUT"; } >testErr.log; cat testErr.log
(no output)
```

You can change `>testErr.log` to `>>testErr.log` to append.

And this can be more efficient:

```
OUT=$(exec df -h 2>&1 >/dev/null) || { date; echo "$OUT"; } >testErr.log
```

Comment: I don't want the time-stamp to be in the file when it runs successfully but your code, as you can see, doing that. This is exactly the issue I'm trying to address. Best!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
date > stderr.log
command 2>> stderr.log
```

That seems the simplest way to me - simply pre-seed your output file with the date, then append the stderr output, instead of overwriting the file...